# urllib2で同ネットワーク内の別サーバにリクエストを送りたい。

Tags: python

Pythonのurllib2で同じネットワークの中の別のサーバにリクエストを送信したいのですが、下記の記述ではできませんでした。

```
urllib2.urlopen('http://[IP Address]/hoge/')
urllib2.urlopen('http://[Domain Name]/hoge/')
```

pingは届いているので80番ポートには繋げられる状況だと思いますが`urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 504: Gateway Time-out`がでてリソースを取得できません。

このようなことは可能でしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

目的のURLにブラウザやcurlからアクセスした場合はきちんと動作していますか？

`504 Gateway Time-out`のような500番台のステータスコードは、サーバ側で問題が発生した可能性が考えられます。もしサーバの管理者であれば再起動したり、アクセスログを確認してはどうでしょうか。何かしらエラー出力が見つかるかもしれません。

Comment: サーバ側にリクエストしたパスを設定し忘れていました。